# Documentation for RANDOM(RAND) in gfortran 4.8.0

Tags: random, numbers, generator

Contrary to what applies for RANDOM_NUMBER and RAND() (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html#RANDOM_005fNUMBER), in the gfortran compiler 4.8.0, there is no documentation (brief or detailed) for a random number generator that runs as RANDOM(RAND). I'm using the Geany 1.23 frontend for gfortran and when I'm calling RANDOM(RAND), "RANDOM" appears in brown, while "RAND" appears in blue.

Any idea as to where I can find documentation for this built-in random number generator? I'm asking because although good random number generation conduct dictates the use of portable code -and I do so-, RANDOM(RAND) appears to work equally well for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Fortran or how to put this message as a comment, but I just wanted to point out that Geany's keywords are just a simple list in a text (config) file and don't necessarily represent a full or accurate set of language/builtin/standard keywords (though they usually do). Looking at Geany's commit history, the 'random' keyword has been in since the Fortran filetype was [initially added](https://github.com/geany/geany/commit/8d581d1552878a7ce3ae4250b82818c4912c1cc4#L2R25), by someone who, as far as I know, neither speaks nor uses Fortran himself.